# Use `&mut Option<PathBuf>` on each iteration of loop

Tags: rust, mutable-reference

I have a situation where I have an `Option<PathBuf>` and I want to pass a mutable reference to it to a function (`do_loop`) and within that function it is passed to a second function (`handle_path`) within in each iteration of a loop. The second function also possibily calls the first function (so this is recursive).
I have attempted to create minimal example from my codebase which hopefully better illustrates what I am trying to achieve. I have tried using `&mut Option<PathBuf>`, `&Option<&mut PathBuf>`, and `Option<&mut PathBuf>` but none have worked. I could solve the problem by cloning the `PathBuf` at some point but I am hoping to avoid this in order to improve the performance and memory usage.

```rust
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn handle_path(path: &mut Option<PathBuf>) {
    match path {
        Some(path) => {
            let check = path.pop();
            if check {
                do_loop(Some(*path));
            }
        }
        None => {}
    }
}

fn do_loop(path: &mut Option<PathBuf>) {
    for i in 0..2 {
        handle_path(path);
    }
}
fn main() {
    do_loop(&mut Some("foo/bar".into()));
    do_loop(&mut None);
}
```

Comment: _"but none have worked."_ Please be specific. "Doesn't work" is not useful troubleshooting information. _What_ doesn't work? Include the behavior you expected and the behavior you see instead. If the compiler yields an error, include the compiler output in your question.

Comment: Just call the `path` inside the `match` something different? You're shadowing the `&mut Option<PathBuf>` with an `&mut PathBuf`, and the latter can't be passed back to `do_loop`. If you rename the inner path `p`, then pass the outer `path` down to the recursive call the snippet compiles fine.

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you are trying to accomplish here; maybe you can add some `assert!`-statements to your code, which need to pass?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While destructuring the option, you reused the same variable name (`path`), thus your parameter (still holding the modified path) is not useable anymore (this is called *shadowing* a variable).
Choosing another name in the pattern matching allows you to pass the same parameter to the recursive call.

```rust
fn handle_path(path: &mut Option<PathBuf>) {
    match path {
        Some(inner_path) => {
            let check = inner_path.pop();
            if check {
                do_loop(path);
            }
        }
        None => {}
    }
}
```